# Why am I getting ngRepeat:dupes when sending data from an Array into a differently named Array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

*[Error: ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=v%20in%20viewTags&p1=object:304&p2=%5B%7B%22name%22:%22Foo%20Bar%201%22,%22details%22:%22Details1%22,%22showDetails%22:false%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22Foo%20Bar%202%22,%22details%22:%22Details2%22,%22showDetails%22:true%7D%5D)*

---

**http://plnkr.co/edit/hZtIXkPM7dhpf4P7rd6W?p=preview**

I have an array which `ng-repeats` a list of tags on the page. Next I have an `ng-click` which sends the tag data into the scope of another controller whois job it is to display those selected tags in another list.

It's easier to see the code in action in the plnkr above, but the basics are:

- the first tags Array is in the cnt controller
- when you click on a tag, it gets stored in the `TagDetailsFactory` service
- I then broadcast an event to the view controller to then call the `getTagDetails` function in `TagDetailsFactory` to retrieve the saved tags and store them into the `viewTags` array in the view controller.

This is where I'm getting the ngDupes error :(

However, the array in `cnt` is named `$scope.tags = [];`
and the array in `view` is `$scope.viewTags = [];`

---

```
// Code goes here

angular.module('app', [])

.directive('tagDetails', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
      // console.debug($scope, attrs);
    },
    scope:{
        tag:'=ngModel'
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="tag.showDetails">{{tag.details}}</div>'
  };
})

.controller('cnt', ['$scope',
                    '$rootScope',
                    'TagDetailsFactory',
                    function($scope,
                             $rootScope,
                             TagDetailsFactory) {
  $scope.tags = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $scope.tags.push(
      { name: 'Foo Bar ' + i, details: 'Details' + i }
    );
  }

  $scope.showTagDetails = function(t) {
    t.showDetails = true;
  }

  $scope.leaveTag = function(t) {
    t.showDetails = false;
  }

  $scope.sendTag = function(t) {
    TagDetailsFactory.saveTagDetails(t);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('updateView');
  }

}])

.factory('TagDetailsFactory', function() {

      var savedTags = [];

      var saveTagDetails = function(tag) {
        savedTags.push(tag);
      }

      var getTagDetails = function() {
        return savedTags;
      }

      return {
          saveTagDetails : saveTagDetails,
          getTagDetails  : getTagDetails
      };
})

.controller('view', ['$scope',
                     '$rootScope',
                     'TagDetailsFactory',
                     function($scope,
                              $rootScope,
                              TagDetailsFactory) {

  $scope.viewTags = [];

  $scope.$on('updateView', function() {
    console.log('updateView');
    var tags = TagDetailsFactory.getTagDetails();
    console.log(tags);
    $scope.viewTags.push(tags);
  });

  // $scope.showTagDetails = function(t) {
  //   t.showDetails = true;
  // }

  // $scope.leaveTag = function(t) {
  //   t.showDetails = false;
  // }

}]);
```

Comment: Did small improvements all over. Check that:  http://plnkr.co/edit/4QMnX5VxdFM1xgUSG62N?p=preview

Comment: Nice, yeah I see this working, and the tags populating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-repeat does not allow duplicate items (otherwise how can it keep track of them, if you wanted to updated something, for example?).
"
In order to deal with this problem, you can add `track by $index` to your ng-repeat value:

```
ng-repeat="data in dataset track by $index"
```

You can have it track by other values in your data also, but it needs to be unique.

[Your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gk8BdMZSo0eYdee3iWzR?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks :) looking forward to never seeing that error message ever again